# Format of Excel drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

When choosing from a drop down list in Excel, is it possible for the cells to change the format when you choose a specific subject?

Each subject has a different format for the cells.

Comment: Have you checked conditional formatting?

Comment: It seems you need use Conditional Formatting for each subject.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the format in the dropdown list cannot be changed, but you can use easily use the custom formula-type conditional formatting (one rule per list item) to say format the cell to red when `=$A$1="item1"`.